# React input select to display corresponding components & select string value to number value

Tags: reactjs, select

I am populating a select list and drawing the corresponding information component from the same json. Select is set up with .map and all the correct values.. (I think). onChange is assigned to countryChange which takes a event value and setStates to pass on a trigger.

What I don't understand is, 
 1. e.target.value is a string instead of a number,
 2. while a state assigned to 0, e.target.value and the state return a different value...

```
this.state={
 selectedCountry:0
}



      countryChange( e ) {
            const list = e.target.value;
            const countrylist = this.props.countries.find(c => c.id === list)
              this.setState({
                    selectedCountry: countrylist
                   // selectedCountry: parseInt(e.target.value, 10) 
                });
            }
        render() {
                    return(
                      <select id="exampleSelect" onChange={this.countryChange.bind(this)}>
                      <option value="d">Select Country</option>
                     {this.props.countries.map((item) => ( <option key={item.id} value={item.id}> { item.name } </option> ))}</select>
```

after, I send the selectedCountry as props to other components to render information. I've been looking at other similar questions and answers and came this far but can't seem to fully execute it the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML `<option>` elements, the `value` attribute is interpreted by browsers as a string. ([HTML specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element) describe it as type `DOMString`.) It looks like you have already figured out that you need to convert this to a number if you want it to be a number, but I think you've done it a bit late to make your comparisons work. How about

```
const list = parseInt(e.target.value);
```

as the first line of `countryChange` instead?

Alternately, you could just make all of your comparisons string comparisons. You would probably want your `.id` properties to be strings, and you'd want your initial `setState` to make `{selectedCountry: "0"}`.